# SharePoint 2013 - People Picker with multiple Domains

Tags: active-directory, people-picker, people-search

At at the momentent I´m investigating a problem with the people picker in my new domain.

**Environment:**

**Old:** OldDomain.com

**New:** NewServiceDomain.root.com (For Serviceaccounts) and NewUserDomain.root.com (For user accounts)

The forrest is root.com

A oneway trust exist between the old an new domain.
The Firewall on the SharePoint Server is off.

**Problem:**
When I´m installing a new SharePoint Environment in the NewServiceDomain.root.com the people picker is not showing up the accounts from the NewUserDomain.root.com but is showing up account from the old domain and the NewServiceDomain.

**I tried already many compinations with stsadm command for the people picker:**

I think this is the right command for my environment: stsadm –o setproperty –url Url –pn peoplepicker-searchadforests –pv “forest:root.com;domain:OldDomain.com

What is the right command? Andy ideas to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a one way trust you need to use username and password as shown below:

"Specify user account and password from a one way trust
To specify the user name and password from a one-way trust, so that People Picker can look up this information, use the following syntax:
`stsadm -o setproperty -url http://<server:port> -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:contoso.corp.com,<LoginName>,<Password>;domain:bar.contoso.corp.com,<LoginName>,<Password>"`"

See this [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for details. Hope this helps!